# Serving custom user controls on webpages: How come all of my DLLs aren't making it to the client?

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, user-controls

I have a UI hosted on a webpage. I'm able to run the control on the server hosting it, but when I attempt to run it from other machines on the intranet, only some of the required DLLs make it to the client.

What direction can I take to investigate why this is happening?

Comment: Please be more specific. What kind of controls are you talking about? ActiveX? ASP.NET? What DLLs did you think would get copied to the client?

Comment: I'm talking about an embedded user control, a .NET .dll form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think an ActiveX control copies DLL's to the client. More likely the clients already had some of the DLLs. You'll need to install the additional DLLs somehow (as a downloadable installer or using custom code). You may run into permissions issues trying to install DLLs via a web page.

Comment: The DLLs end up in the temporary internet files.